# how to support the special latex characters in Matlab plot title

Tags: matlab, symbols

I'm trying to type `\digamma`. In latex, this character is supported  in `\usepackage{amssymb}`. In Matlab, I can set the interpreter to be Latex as follows

```
Figure1=figure(1)
set(Figure1,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex');
```

but the aforementioned character is not supported. Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: @thewaywewalk, it is not working.

Comment: "not working" is a rather incomplete error description. Please post the steps you've done and what was the result/error.

Comment: @thewaywewalk, the answer provided in the link addresses the problem in a general manner however in this link https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/283068 the answer is complete. However Matlab throws out a warning that is `Warning: Unable to interpret LaTeX string "$\digamma$" ` even though I have loaded the correct packages according to the aforementioned link.

Comment: does `'$$\digamma$$'` work?

Comment: Are you trying to typeset the symbols in Matlab, or is your aim to typeset the symbols when importing Matlab graphics to LaTeX?

Comment: @thewaywewalk, no.

Comment: @Johannes_B, I'm trying to type `\digamma` in the title of a plot in Matlab.

Comment: So, this has nothing to do with LaTeX?

Comment: @StrongBad There is a chance that your link can answer OP. (I do not have Matlab to test.) But I found latex unnecessary if OP can insert `U+03DC` directly. In the latter case it would be **off topic** rather than **duplicated**.

Comment: @StrongBad, the answer in the link is not thorough and it is not working. Also, I don't know why this topic has been migrated in here. I asked the question in Stack Overflow.